# require folder crash on heroku with node js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a beginning of rest api that work locally :

[image: file listing]

And this is the content of index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var userController = require(__dirname + './controller/User.js');
/*var authController = require('./controller/auth');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://server:mongolab0809@ds063870.mongolab.com:63870/diffuse');

var router = express.Router();
router.route('/users')
    .post(userController.postUsers)
    .get(authController.isAuthenticated,  userController.getUsers);

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);*/

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.send('Welcome on guarded-sea-3175!');
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'));
});
```

when heroku server arrive on `userController = require(__dirname + './controller/User.js');` it crash. I tried without dirname and and every case possible for the file name but I really don't know what is wrong here and I didn't find any relative post to this error.

what I have on my heroku web page :

> "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

And the heroku log :

```
2015-03-19T00:11:33.818642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 
host=guarded-sea-3175.herokuapp.com request_id=f7bf879e-c606-4a0f-bdae-7e3c9a33dcf5 fwd="82.235.64.7" 
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

If I comment the require line, everything works fine.

Comment: What's the Current Working Directory of the app? `process.cwd()` should help.

Comment: I commented the require functions and display the value of `process.cwd()` and `__dirname`, it's actually the same : /app. So I tried a `require("../User");` but I still get th error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When requiring the file you should leave out the __dirname since you can just require relative to the path of the index.js file. You should also leave off the '.js' when requiring file. Also make sure you file name matches (case sensitive) because 'User.js' is different than 'user.js'

Try:

```
var userController = require('./controller/User');
```

Comment: I already tried this way, but it doesn't work neither, same error message.

Comment: Can you double check your folder structure and file names and list that here? If it is as you have it listed here there is no reason you should be receiving this error.

Comment: If you look in the logs on heroku do you get an actual stack trace being logged? If so can you paste that here? Maybe the error isn't with requiring the User controller but with the contents of the user controller. Can you also paste those here? The error displayed by heroku is just a general crash error. It could be due to the fact that it can't find the User file (but based on your file structure it should find it just fine) or it could be due to some other error inside the User.js file.

Comment: Yep you were wright ! The error was coming from User.js file, I was requiring a file without correct name (case sensitive error). Thanks for the help !!